# bootstrap classes are working but only partly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[I used bootstrap classes in HTML code .However,some of these classes are working but the rest is not. why its like that? I used the bootstrap link in the correct place Idk what else to do .for example hover and striped classes don't work but table-dark class is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH8qg.png)

Comment: Can you at least show the structure or the order in which you included the bootstrap files?

Comment: Either you have the name of the class wrong or you have another css overriding bootstrap, could you provide the html and css?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement (and shouldn't be one giant link). We don't debug images.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you're using the official bootstrap links `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/`
- Have you added other css files? - use the developer tool to make sure other classes isn't blocking it (write inline css code to debug, and use !important in the css too)